# GELF json logs stop arriving on graylog after some time from nginx proxy in docker

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, graylog, alpine

Hmm..where to start...i've got an application stack (running in docker swarm), with nginx as proxy in front. Ive got json-formatted logs, being sent to graylog via gelf.

Container system is alpine 3.11.5 and nginx version is 1.17.10

nginx.conf template (we use 1024 worker connetions and 10M body size):

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid         /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections ${MAX_CONNECTIONS};
}

http {
        log_format json escape=json 
            '{'
            '"remoteAddress": "$remote_addr", '
            '"remoteUser": "$remote_user", '
            '"localTime": "$time_iso8601", '
            '"request":"$request", '
            '"requestLength": $request_length, '
            '"requestProcessTime": $request_time, '
            '"responseStatus": $status, '
            '"bodyBytesSent": $body_bytes_sent, '
            '"httpReferer":"$http_referer",'
            '"httpUserAgent": "$http_user_agent",'
            '"http_x_forwarded_for":"$http_x_forwarded_for"'
        '}';

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type    application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log json;

        sendfile    on;
        #tcp_nopush on;
        server_tokens   off;

        keepalive_timeout   65;

        #gzip   on;

        client_max_body_size ${MAX_BODY_SIZE};

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

conf.d/proxy.conf template

```
server {
    listen ${Port} default_server;
    listen [::]:${Port} default_server;

    server_name proxy;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    location ~^/help(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://help$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ ^/api/(.*?)/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$1:8080/$1/$2$is_args$args;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

Docker compose logs config:

```
logging:
        driver: gelf
        options:
          gelf-address: "udp://ip-in-here:12201"
          tag: "dev-proxy"
```

And it works. Nicely json formatted access logs land on graylog. For a while.

After random ammount of time, access logs are no more, and all that lands on graylog is "an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file while reading upstream". Ive spent good few hours googling stuff, messing around with buffers (disabling proxy_cache, disabling proxy_buffers, increasing proxy_buffers, proxy_buffer_size and proxy_busy_buffers_size), but to no effect. When i disable proxy buffering, there are no log at all. Ofc, stack is working properly and all request are proxied - just no more access log from the proxy.

However, when i change access_log to save to a file (instead of redirecting it to stdout), all access logs save to file, properly formatted.

Updating service / closing proxy container doesnt help. Fully removing stack and deploying it again helps. Until it repeats.

Any ideas what may be the issue here and where should i look?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cIm5.png)